# Reverse Apple Music Play Order

Tags: itunes, music

For the longest time my Apple Music Playlists have been playing in reverse order.  Albums too.  What do I mean by that...

[image]
You can see that Meat Loaf "Original Sin" is the first song in the list.  But it is the last track in the "Up Next".  I can't find any setting to fix this.  I've even tried opening `com.apple.iTunes.plist` with no luck.  I can't find the setting.

This only happens on my desktop machine.  My laptop works fine.

Please help.

Comment: Removed my other useless comments. I found many posts online about this problem, but I could not replicate it at all. Could you make sure you got the latest version of itunes ( 12.6. )? I'd perhaps try a clean install, using something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to uninstall it. Then again, I have no local songs, so it may be something you can't do.

Comment: Yes it's the latest (I'm fanatical about staying updated).  I have a lot of music I'm unwilling to delete from my local system.  So deletion is not an option.